# Calling outerclass from innerclass with a thread in MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, inner-classes

I am using a MVC model and am trying to create a thread in the controller.  When I am in the inner class run() I need to get the correct model but it is throwing a null pointer.

Here is the code to create the inner class and thread from the outer controller:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new runWithThread(OpsSec, AmToChange, AgentID, balance, currency, selected_account_obj));
thread.start();
```

Inside the runWithThread I try to get the correct Model. AMModel is the Model class and withdraw is a method inside it.  getModel is defined in the abstract controller I am extending(implementation inheritance).

```
((AMModel)getModel()).withdraw(10, "USD");
```

It works in the outer class but not in the inner class and I am not sure why I am getting the null pointer with the ((AMModel)getModel()).  Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Is the Model being injected by a container of some sort? If thats the case then you need to declare it in the inner class also. Otherwise it simply would not exist in the inner class.

Comment: Post the stacktrace, the code of `getModel()` and the associate  declarations and initializing code.

Answer (score 1):

I realized the error.  I had "extends AbstractController" in both the controller outer class and in runWithThread inner class.  I am using Rational Arch and it didn't flag anything so I didn't notice the error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old, but try `AMModel.this.withdraw(10, "USD");`. Here's a generic example:

```
class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {
        public void test()
        {
            Outer.this.variable = 1;
        }
    }
    public int variable = 0;
    private Inner inner;
}
```

After calling `inner.test()`, `variable` would be `1`.